# Sulu not running on PHP7

Tags: doctrine-orm, sulu

was any one of you able to install sulu on a webserver running Apache and PHP7?

When I try to clear the cache, I get an error `PHP Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in /var/www/foobar/vendor/doctrine/phpcr-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/PHPCR/Mapping/Annotations/String.php on line 28`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are already working on that. The main problem is the usage of a class named `String` in the PHPCR-ODM. They fixed that in version 1.3. Also there are some tests still failing, but we are already working on that. You can follow the progress on the [corresponding PR](https://github.com/sulu-io/sulu-standard/pull/579).